# Keras - Binary Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, keras, training-data

I am currently trying to use satellite imagery to recognize Apples orchards. And I am facing a small problem in the number of representative data for each class.

In fact my question is :

> Is it possible to take randomly some different images in my "not-apples" class at each epoch because I have much more of theses (compared to the "apples" one) and I want to increase the probability my network will classify out an image unrepresentative.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible in Keras.  Keras will, by default, shuffle your training data and then train on it in a mini-batch fashion. However, there are still ways to re-balance your dataset.

The imbalanced training data problem that you are facing is pretty common.  You have many options available to you; I list a few below:

1. You can adjust the relative weights of your classes using `class_weight` keyword of the `model.fit()` function.
2. You can "up-sample" your "apples" class or "down-sample" your "non-apples" class to have equal numbers of both classes during training.
3. You can generate synthetic images of your "apples" class to augment your data set.  To this end, the [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) class in Keras can be particularly useful.  This [Keras tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) is a good introduction to its usage.

In my experience, I've found #2 and #3 to be most useful. #1 is limited by the fact that the convergence of stochastic gradient descent suffers when using class weights differing by a couple orders of magnitude and smaller batch sizes.

Jason Brownlee has put together [a list of tactics for dealing with imbalanced classes](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) that might also be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks ! I will augment my apples dataset then, seems like the good plan :)